Displaying count of the same column from two different tables
A site I'm working on has a (badly-named) column postcode that contains postcodes for UK customers and ISO 3166-1 alpha 2 (i.e. two-letter country codes) for international customers. Using my very deficient SQL knowledge I've managed to cobble together a query that returns a mostly decent-looking list of all the unique country codes and a count of them (i.e. the international countries in which the company has had at least one customer).

SELECT 
    postcode as postcode,
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    ""
FROM 
    transactions
WHERE 
    LENGTH(postcode) = 2
GROUP BY 
    postcode
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    "",
    'Total Unique Countries' AS postcode,
    COUNT(distinct postcode) as total
FROM 
    transactions
WHERE 
    LENGTH(postcode) = 2
ORDER BY IF(postcode = 'Total', 1, 0), postcode

However, I now need to modify this query to count "postcodes" from one more table, called transactions_original. Just adding this table to the WHERE clauses seemingly runs fine but doesn't actually show any of the data from the table. As far as I can tell what I'm trying to do here is called a join, but I can't figure out how to incorporate it into my mess of a query. Suggestions on optimising the query are also more than welcome.

Why are you using UNION at all? The results of these queries have totally different meaning, so they should be two separate queries.

Also you should store the country code in its own column. That way you don't have to search based on the length. I think your data model is poorly designed. An RDBMS is not a spreadsheet.

@BillKarwin Because I don't know SQL that well. In what way do they have different meaning? They're two columns with the same data format, even the same length, that I'm trying to aggregate into one count. And obviously, changing the database structure on a production ecommerce site is out of the question, but I don't personally think needing to search for the length in code is a bad tradeoff for one less, very similar column in the table.

The values in a given column should be comparable. In your example you have the string 'Total Unique Countries' above the integers that represent the counts. These are dissimilar values, not from the same domain. But in relational database theory, all the values in a given column must be from the same domain. If they aren't, then features like data types and constraints don't work.

Another way of thinking of this is if you are a Java programmer (or any other language) and you declare an integer variable called count. Should you store a string in that variable? No — it's not the right type and it's not a sensible use of that variable.

There's no advantage to sticking queries together with UNION when they are really meant to produce dissimilar results. If you're padding results with empty strings (as you show above), that's a strong indication that the query results aren't appropriate to be unioned. Just run two separate queries. It's easier to manage them in your application, especially as you need to make modifications to either query.

@BillKarwin Fair enough, that was just a hack to quickly show a header for the count. I'd be happy to see an answer that does this properly, although if I'm understanding you correctly, running (i.e. executing?) a whole separate query just to show a header for the data of the previous execution doesn't exactly seem ideal.

You asked for an answer to show how to do this properly. I understand it would take some changes to your data storage.
First group by country_code instead of postcode. This means the table should have a different column that stores the two-character country code. One of these country codes should be UK.
SELECT 
    country_code
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM 
    transactions
GROUP BY 
    country_code;

Then to show the total unique countries, you can do a second query. The label 'Total Unique Countries' should be a column header, defined as an alias, not a string value in one of the rows.
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT country_code) as `Total Unique Countries`
FROM 
    transactions;

Now both of these queries are simpler and easier to read. They do not contain "spacer" columns. They're ready to be modified if new requirements are added.
You also mentioned some requirement to combine data with another table transactions_original, but you haven't described enough information about what's in that table or how it relates to the first table to write a solution.
